# How to dynamically resize the buttons & labels in monotouch Xamarin

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In xcode I have designed with buttons containing labels I want to resize the buttons and labels depending upon the content.

[image]

Comment: The design you are creating there should rather be a `UITableView`. Then you can override `GetHeightForRow()` and adjust to your content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

- you can either adjust the size of your controls yourself, in that case, you would override the ViewDidLoad method in the UIViewController and then set the Frame properties of each one of your views manually.
- You can use Autolayout to provide rules for how the different elements are displayed on your view.   Here is your guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html
- You can use a library like MonoTouch.Dialog, which you can use to create the entire UI.   MonoTouch Dialog support creating custom views that you can render, so you could use that to have special versions of each view: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/